# how to hide the url when passing the data through href link in jsp page

Tags: jsp

How can I pass the data from one JSP to another when clicking on a `href` link. At that time I need to hide the data in `url`.

```
<table  id="results" class="ex2 headQ"  width="550px" >
        <%
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        %>
        <tr></tr>

        <tr class="mycolor">  
            <%
                Query studentDetailsDTO = (Query) list.get(i);
                out.println("<td class='divClass'><a href=''>" +studentDetailsDTO.getTitle()+"</a></td>");
            %>
        </tr>

        <tr>  
            <%
                out.println("<td class='wrapword'> " + studentDetailsDTO.getQuestion() + "</td>");
            %>
        </tr>
        <%
            }
        %>
</table>
```

Comment: What data ? If you mean data conserved server side between clicks, you need to handle sessions (google jsp session). If you want to hide the parameters you send from the browser, you may use ajax requests or simply forms in POST.